# Text from webpage

Tags: vb.net

I need to get some text from [this web page](http://openbook.etoro.com/ahanit/#/profile/Trades/). I want to use the trade feed for my program to analyse the sentiment of the markets.

I used the browser control and the get element command but its not working. The problem is that whenever my browser starts to open the page I get Java scripts errors.

I tried with DOM but seems that i dont quite understand what i need to do :)
Here is the code:

```
Dim code As String
    Using client As New WebClient

        code = client.DownloadString("http://openbook.etoro.com/ahanit/#/profile/Trades/")
    End Using

    Dim htmlDocument As IHTMLDocument2 = New HTMLDocument(code)
    htmlDocument.write(htmlDocument)


    Dim allElements As IHTMLElementCollection = htmlDocument.body.all

    Dim allid As IHTMLElementCollection = allElements.tags("id")
    Dim element As IHTMLElement

    For Each element In allid
        element.title = element.innerText
        MsgBox(element.innerText)

    Next
```

**Update:** So I tried the HTML Agility pack, as suggested in the comments, and I am stuck again on this code

```
    Dim plain As String = String.Empty
    Dim htmldoc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
    htmldoc.LoadHtml("http://openbook.etoro.com/ahanit/#/profile/Trades/")
    Dim goodnods As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection =                               htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("THE PROBLEM")

    For Each node In goodnods
        TextBox1.Text = htmldoc.DocumentNode.InnerText
    Next
```

Any advice what to now?

Ok I think I know what the problem is somehow the div that I need is hidden and its not loaded when I load the web page just the source code. Does someone knows how to load all the hidden divs ??

Here is my new code

```
Dim doc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
    Dim web As New HtmlWeb


    doc = web.Load("http://openbook.etoro.com/ahanit/#/profile/Trades/")

    Dim nodes As HtmlNode = doc.GetElementbyId("feed-items")

    Dim id As String = nodes.WriteTo()
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & vbCrLf & id
```

Comment: Have you tried HTML Agility ack : http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thank you Shoban, but nothing there that i understand :) i dont have much exp with vb all the code above is the result of 3day googling and still know end in sight :)

Comment: shoban if you now how it works plzz some advice :)

Comment: Sorry have not worked with it much. Do you get any output when you run the code?

Comment: Yes I just got "false" in text box when I use tags but without i got the url of the site I think Im on the right way :)

Answer (score 0):

user1336635,

Welcome to SO! Something you might try is to check out his source code, figure out what javascript function is populating the field you want (using firebug - I assume it's the one that "trades result in profit" next to it), and then embedding that script into a web page that your webbrowser control loads. That's where I'd try to start. I checked his source code and searched for "trades result in profit" and didn't find anything which leads me to believe hunting for the element 'might' not be possible. Just a starting place until someone with more experience with this chimes in!! Best!

-sf

Comment: Nice to know that its possible to get the text so my effort was not a waste of time :) The problem is that i dont have any exp in server side languages i must find a other way to get around without complicating things to much for me :) thank you

Comment: You're welcome bro! I'm actually not sure if you need server stuff. I was just suggesting finding the javascript responsible for calculating the percentage and running it yourself (sort of bypassing his website). If you know that you can get the text, then the element you're looking for is in the class 'profile-win-ratio' (I went ahead and tracked it for ya)

Comment: I dont need any percent i just need for example: "ahanit closed a Buy EUR/USD position, copied from Moksel1972, gaining 5%" Im not interested in the gain i just need the information that a trader opened a position or closed thats all :) thank you